# proxy_wstunnel_moduleのインストール方法

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, websocket

Ubuntu 12.04
apache2: Server version: Apache/2.2.22
 * sudo apt-get install apache2　でインストール
の構成ですが、
proxy_wstunnel_moduleをインストールしたいと思っています。

/etc/apache2/mods-availableの中にもなく、
proxy_wstunnel_module.so
をfindで探しましたが、ありません。

どのようにインストールするかご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

---

apache2.4をインストールしました。mod_proxy_wstunnelもenableにしました。
apacheの設定を

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ubuntu.jp
    ServerAlias www.ubuntu.jp
    DocumentRoot /var/ubuntu
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    Alias /node /var/ubuntu/node

    <Location /node/>
      ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
      ProxyPass ws://localhost:3000/
      ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
      ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:3000/
      Require all granted
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ubuntu_error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ubuntu_access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off

    <Directory "/var/ubuntu/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

にしていますが、Socket通信ができません。
対処方法ご存知の方はご教示のほど何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

mod_proxy_wstunnel は Apache httpd バージョン 2.4 から利用できるモジュールです。
バージョン 2.2 には含まれていません。

ubuntu から Apache httpd 2.4 が提供されていればそれを、
提供されていなければ、バージョン 2.2 用のパッチを Apache httpd 2.2.x のソースコードに適用してコンパイルするか、Apache httpd 2.4.x をソースコードからコンパイルするか。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390544/installing-apache-2-4-and-php-5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04　を参考にapache2.4をインストールしましたが、PHPが動かなかったりcURLが動かなかったり(FB APIで利用)、基本認証モジュールが動かなかったり(phpMyAdminで利用)で四苦八苦しながらインストールしました。
本当にこのインストール方法で間違いないのでしょうか？

Comment: Ubuntuを 14.04にバージョンアップしたところ、apacheも2.4.7がすんなりインストールができて、無事にmod_proxy_wstunnelが入りました。でもモジュールの名称はproxy_wstunnel.loadです。こちらと同一ですよね?

Comment: /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy_wstunnel.load はモジュールをロードするための設定が記載されているファイルです。
モジュールの実体は /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so です。
"sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel" でモジュールを有効にします(/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ 以下にシンボリックリンクを作成)。
 
(参考) https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

Comment: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_scgi.soは存在していましたが、"sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel" を行うと"ERROR: Module poxy_wstunnel does not exist!"との表示でした。こちらは存在しないとのことですか？対処方法をご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: あ、間違いました。
モジュールの実体は /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so です。
ありませんか？

Comment: proxy_wstunnel.loadをmoreするとおっしゃる通りLoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.soの記載があります。モジュールの実態も /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so にありました。こちら、/etc/apache2/mods-enabled配下にproxy_wstunnel.loadのみ存在すればいいのですよね？(a2enmod済み)

Answer (score 1):

(追加の質問について)

http: の行が先にあるので、mod_proxy_http が使われているのだと思います。
ws: のみでいいと思います。

```
ProxyPass ws://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: socket.io/socket.io.jsを読み込むのに、httpもProxyPassReverseしなければいけないかと思っています。記載の順番が異なるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

`ProxyPass`を2つ書いても先に有る方で処理されます。
`ProxyPassMatch` で ws への転送ルールを指定して、次に `ProxyPass` でそれ以外を http に転送すればどうでしょう。

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/node/正規表現パターン$ ws://localhost:3000/
ProxyPass /node/ http://localhost:3000/
```

どういう正規表現パターンを書けばいいかはご質問からは読み取れませんでした。